# How create a new module in IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am really new in all the IntelliJ plugins development and I really need to know how can I create a new module type from a IntelliJ plugin. 
I have found some similars answers but there dont explain me what I need to do, there is some tutorial about this? I appreciate all the help...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you have the latest intelliJ build (12.1.X). Either community or ultimate edition should be ok.

Then, here is some info to get started.

[Plugin Development Confluence](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment)

[Plugin Development Guidelines](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/plugin-development-guidelines.html)

Maybe if you try to get it up and running and come back with specific questions we can be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for anwser me, those links that you give are really helpful. In order to be more specific I need to create a custom project & module and I can't find information about, can you help me?

Comment: Please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951117/how-do-i-register-a-new-module-type-in-an-intellij-plugin/26911457#26911457